# Port Forwarding, WAN IP forwards to router but not computer

Tags: routing, port-forwarding, xampp, ubuntu-13.04

I already set up my router to forward to a specific LAN IP but when I test entering my WAN IP it pops up the router's authentication box meaning that it doesnt forward to my computer but instead to the router, how can I solved this?

I followed this guide: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/ZTE/ZXV10-W300v3/defaultguide.htm

I want to forward WAN IP (Example: 123.456.789:456) to my LAN IP(Example: 192.168.0.120) which has ubuntu 13.04 with xampp...thanks!!

```
Rule     Application     Protocol    Start Port  End Port    Local IP Address    Start Port Local    End Port Local
1        XAMPP_ubuntu       ALL      456         456        192.168.0.120        80                  80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forwarding rule appears to be set up correctly. If you are trying to access the web server by the router's WAN IP address from inside the network, then the problem is likely not the configuration, but a lack of hairpin NAT support. Accessing a machine on the local network by its external IP requires the router to rewrite the headers, or no connection can be established. Many routers do not support this feature.

Try to access the webserver from outside your local network. If that succeeds, you'll know your configuration is sound.